# Doctrine2 get join results when child is empty

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm working with Doctrine2 in a Symfony2 project, where I'm trying to optimize queries and lazy loading.

I have two entities `Parent` and `Child`.

Now, if in my controller I retrieve an specific `Parent` and I pass it through a view (twig) all works fine, but when I want to show data related to `Child` Doctrine2 makes another query.

I've tried to make my own `DQL` to obtain all in only one query (an specific `Parent` with all of its `Child`s. All works good if a `Parent` has at least one `Child`, but if there's not any `Child`I obtain a null result.

This is my `DQL`:

```
$dql = ' SELECT p, c
        FROM AppBundle:Parent p
        JOIN p.childs c
        WHERE p.id = :parentId
          AND c.state = :state';
```

---

#### Solution:

```
$dql = 'SELECT p, c
            FROM AppBundle:Parent p
            LEFT JOIN p.childs c
            WHERE p.id = :parentId
              AND (c.state = :state' or c.state is null);
```

Comment: c.state = :state will always fail if there is no child.  Thus no records.

Comment: You're right! Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add *SOLVED* in the title and the answer in the question. You should accept any answer that helped you, it looks like you copy-pasted the answer from sagi. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/237701).

Comment: Sorry! I didn't know that! Thanks! Should I remove solved in the title? Regarsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a left join instead of an inner join:

```
SELECT p, c
    FROM AppBundle:Parent p
    JOIN p.childs c
    WHERE p.id = :parentId
      AND (c.state = :state or c.state is null)
```

This will basically keep all results from the left table(in this case the parent table) and will keep only the matching results from the right table(the childs table)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this option, but I don't know why, well, of course I was doing something wrong, it didn't work. I'll try again!

Comment: Btw, the alias part LEFT JOIN P.child c seems a little wierd.. P is the alias of the other table @Plagueis

Comment: Maybe that's the problem... should I use LEFT JOIN c.parent p ?

Comment: Try it now @Plagueis

Comment: Doctrine's DQL is not SQL.  What you posted will not work.  Downvoted.

Comment: My bad, wasn't paying attention.. will be deleted tommarow when I regain my delete amount @Cerad

Comment: Fair enough.  If you edit the answer then I'll remove the down vote.  The basic problem is that child.state = :state will always fail if there are no children.

Comment: @Cerad edited the answer, this is what you meant right?

Comment: Thanks @Cerad and sagi , the final solution is, like the last edited, but with a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `setFetchMode()`. You can tell doctrine to load all associations with single query.

https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql

Edit: You can set fetch mode in [annotations as well](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone).

Comment: Wow. I didn't know this option. I'll try, it seems really clean!

Comment: Your solution works, but if I want more than one relation, how should I do it?

Comment: Then call the function multiple times for each association.